# How to use proc mean in this case

Tags: sas

I have been try to formulate this code.
However, i get an error on the 5 lines of code.( Refer to the screen shot).
Kindly let me know how i can rectify the code.

[image: Link to screenshot of my code]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot divide summary variables in the `proc means` `output out` statement. Use a separate datastep:

```
proc means data = sashelp.class noprint;
    output out = class_ratio
    sum(weight) = total_weight
    sum(height) = total_height;
run;

data class_ratio1; set class_ratio;
    total_ratio = total_height/total_weight;
    format total_ratio percent5.2;
run;
```